# How to exit a program when user inputs a special character

Tags: c++, cin

i'm curently doing a simple program that consists of a while-loop that reads in two ints and then prints them out. My question is, how can I exit the program when the user inputs the caracter "|"? Here is this little super simple program:

```
int main()
{
    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 0;

    while(cin>>var1>>var2)
    {
        cout << var1 << " " << var2 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know that you can define an argument to getline that does exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how to implement this in a while-loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you asking how to terminate the loop when var1 or var2 (after being read) contain the pipe character? I suspect not - maybe describe what you want, with example input in more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop will already exit as soon as someone enters something istream cannot << into an integer. Anyway to exit specifically at |, I would use the peek function like so:

```
int main()
{    
  int var1 = 0;    
  int var2 = 0;
  while( cin.good() )
  {
    char c;
    c = cin.peek();

    if( c == | )
      break;
    else
    {
      cin >> var1 >> var2;
      cout << var1 << " " << var2 << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It avoids using c-style input or complex line parsing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But when I enter this in my compiler I get errors: error C3867: 'std::ios_base::good': function call missing argument list; use '&std::ios_base::good' to create a pointer to member  AND fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s)

Comment: @bobiscool cin.good is a function and shoudl be cin.good(). Sorry about that, I wrote it at the top of my head. I don't have access to a compiler at this moment :), I will change my original post now

Comment: The code runs now, but when I enter two ints it prints an infinit amount of 0's on the screen and I can't enter anything else, why is that?

Comment: @bobiscool wow omg, I would vote my own answer down if I could at this point. Its because the loop keeps couting var1 and var2 and not waiting for any input, there is no line of code there that says loop wait for input: but never fear, there will be after I edit it.

Comment: @Avram: The extraction blocks. But test `cin` not `cin.good()`.

Comment: Wow, I should have also seen that myself, should of investigated more before posting, but anyway, now it works perfectly, thanks again for the answer.

Comment: What's the `if( c == | )` part?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to check if the value that was input was | in an if-block and then use the break keyword to stop the loop.

Something in the lines like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    for(;;) {
        printf( "\nPress any key, Q to quit: " );

        // Convert to character value
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == 'Q')
            break;
    }
 } // Loop exits only when 'Q' is pressed
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, you'll exit the loop if the user enters `|`.  Or
anything else that cannot be interpreted as an `int` (after
skipping leading white space).

If you want more precise control, you'll have to read line by
line (and parse the line), or character by character (and build
up the values).